Rsync link to remote server in bash script without password prompt
I have set up public key authentication on an Ubuntu (22.04) server. I can log in to the server via SSH without having to provide a password.
I want to run a backup script on another machine (a Synology NAS) which will back up files from the Ubuntu server to the Synology NAS. I have this working well using rsync.
The only difficulty is that the backup script stops to prompt for a password whenever it executes the rsync command. Obviously this is not suitable for a script that must run automatically and unattended.
The rsync command is something like this:
rsync -av --delete \
     user@10.0.0.9:/path/to/dir \
     link-dest /synology/path/to/dir_last_backup  \
     /synology/path/to/dir_new_backup

When I run the command in the ssh shell it runs without asking for a password, but as soon as I put it into a script it prompts for a password.
How do I get the script to run the command without prompting for a password?
Thank you!

"When I run the command in the ssh shell it runs without asking for a password, but as soon as I put it into a script it prompts for a password." - please can you demonstrate this in your question

Are you running the script as the same user as the interactive command that works? From the same source to the same target?

Thank you for your replies, Chris. I see that I was running the script as root, rather than as Bruce (i.e. the user from which I ran the command on the command line). Running it as Bruce sorts out the problem.

Great! If you write that as an answer then tomorrow you can accept it ✓ to show that it worked for you
